# HTTP URLs availability test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

A Rails application has to be tested for availability and right response of several URLs. I am completely unaware of testing terminology. Could you give me a right name of such testing? What are the Rails native tools (if any) to test this? Cucumber? Selenium Web driver? Or something more appropriate and more native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably take a look at [rspec-rails](http://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) if you don't use any testing framework yet. And then depending on the need you can test on different levels, like:

1. [routing-specs](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-1/docs/routing-specs) - to check if routes are generated properly
2. [controller-specs](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-1/docs/controller-specs) - to check if you get proper response from controller
3. [feature-specs](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-1/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec) - make a full page test